# Resize android layout above soft keyboard input

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, android-constraintlayout, autoresize

I have a view that uses constraint layout. The view has an edit text and expects the soft keyboard input to show up. There are two buttons pinned to the bottom of the screen(Previous and Next). When the soft keyboard opens up, the two buttons hide behind the keyboard. However, I want the layout to resize so that the buttons are above the soft keyboard and not behind it. 
I have the following in my manifest.

```
   <activity
        android:name=".activity.SomeActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
    </activity>
```

I have looked at various other posts and tried a few different things like, adjustPan. I have set

```
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
```

But both of them did not work.

My Constraint layout looks like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                                   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                                                   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                                                   android:id="@+id/container"
                                                   android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                                   android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                                   android:background="@color/colorLibWhite"
                                                   android:focusable="true"
                                                   android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                                                   tools:context=".ui.main.question.QuestionFragment">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:background="@color/colorLibWhite"
        android:indeterminate="false"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progress_bar_background"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/sectionHeader"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@color/colorLibLighterGray"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="2"
        android:paddingStart="16dp"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        android:paddingEnd="16dp"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
        android:text="new section"
        android:textColor="@color/colorLibGray"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/questionLabel"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/progressBar"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/questionLabel"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:text="@string/placeholder"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/inputContainerCL"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/sectionHeader"/>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/inputContainerCL"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/prevNextContainer"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/questionLabel">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/inputContainer"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/hintText"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:text="Hint text goes here"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/inputContainer"/>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/prevNextContainer"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/previous"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:background="@drawable/primary_button"
            android:text="@string/question_previous"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/next"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:background="@drawable/primary_button"
            android:text="@string/question_next"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

EditText is added programatically.

```
 var editText = CustomEditText(context)
        editText.apply {
            id = View.generateViewId()
            layoutParams = ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
            setSingleLine(true)
            imeOptions = EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE
            val questionType = question.validation?.type
            if (questionType == Validation.Type.INTEGER) {
                inputType = InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER or InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_SIGNED
            } else if (questionType == Validation.Type.NUMBER) {
                inputType = InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER or InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_SIGNED or InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL
            } else if (questionType == Validation.Type.MRN) {
                inputType = InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER
                filters = arrayOf(InputFilter.LengthFilter(9))
            } else if (questionType == Validation.Type.ZIP_CODE) {
                inputType = InputType.TYPE_CLASS_PHONE
                filters = arrayOf(InputFilter.LengthFilter(10))
            } else if (questionType == Validation.Type.PHONE) {
                inputType = InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER
                editText.setSelection(editText.text?.length!!)
                editText.addTextChangedListener(PhoneFormatterTextWatcher(editText))
            }
            tag = TAG_FOCUS_FIRST
        }
        editText.setText(question.value ?: "")
        if (question.validation?.type == Validation.Type.ZIP_CODE) {
            editText.addTextChangedListener(ZipCodeTextWatcher(editText, question, updateCallback))
        } else {
            editText.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
                override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {
                    //
                }

                override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {
                    //
                }

                override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
                    question.value = if (s != null && s.isNotBlank()) s.toString() else null
                    updateCallback()
                }

            }
            )
        }
        editText.setOnEditorActionListener() { v, actionId, event ->
            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
                doneCallback()
                true
            } else {
                false
            }
        }

        return editText
```

Here is the code that adds this view to input container

```
inputContainer.addView(editText)
```

Answer (score 0):

Where is your EditText view?.I think you must learn about Constraint Layout. how ever you can try this xml layout code..
Add your styles for views.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    tools:context=".ui.main.question.QuestionFragment">

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:layout_width="411dp"
    android:layout_height="7dp"
    android:indeterminate="false"
    android:progress="40"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/sectionHeader"
    android:layout_width="99dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:maxLines="2"
    android:paddingStart="16dp"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:paddingTop="8dp"
    android:paddingEnd="16dp"
    android:paddingBottom="8dp"
    android:text="new section"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/progressBar" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/questionLabel"
    android:layout_width="379dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:text="questionLabel"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/sectionHeader" />

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/inputContainerCL"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/prevNextContainer"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/questionLabel">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/inputContainer"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/hintText"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:text="text"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/hintText"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:text="Hint text goes here"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/prevNextContainer"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/previous"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:text="question_previous"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/next"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:text="question_next"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[this is the preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/irIKk.png)

Comment: EditText is added programatically. The input container is replaced dynamically based on input type. I have added the code that actually creates the edit text.

Comment: ok remove EditText From my layout file and add it at run-time.